# How to align text differently in different columns using CSS columns property?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using the CSS `columns` property to break a block of dynamic content (a WYSIWYG field in a WordPress site) into two columns. I'd like the text in column 1 to be right-aligned and the text in column 2 to be left-aligned, creating a symmetrical text alignment around a central axis, like this:

[image: Symmetrical text alignment around a central axis]

Because the content is dynamic and may be changed in the future via the site's CMS, I can't wrap or subdivide the content to apply CSS rules to certain parts of it.

Is it possible to target the columns themselves somehow, so that no matter what is fed in, everything before the column break is aligned one way and everything after it another?

Thanks.

My PHP:

```
<?php if(get_field('intro_heading') ): ?>
  <h1 class="centeralign largebotpad"><?php the_field('intro_heading')?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="twocol-text">
  <?php the_field('intro_copy')?>
</div>
```

Which yields this HTML:

```
<h1 class="centeralign largebotpad">Why no plastic?</h1>
<div class="twocol-text">
    <p>Over the past few decades, plastic has increasingly become an integral part of our daily lives. The issue with our reliance on plastic, though, is that this relationship comes at significant environmental cost.</p>
    <p>Water bottles, product packaging, textiles, grocery bags, and medical supplies, all contribute to the more than 400 million tons of plastic produced every single year worldwide. Of that, less than 10% is being recycled, and the vast majority is accumulating in landfills or sloughing off in the natural environment as litter.</p>
    <p>Plastic is also a threat to wildlife, creeping up in the food chain all the way to our plates. It is predicted that by 2050, there will be over 12 billion metric tons of plastic sitting in landfills. Yikes.</p>
    <p>In 2018 we decided to make our own line of clean containers and housewares that will be part of the solution. We opted for tried-and-true stainless steel as our main canvas to create elegant and minimalist, sturdy, and easy to clean products for children and adults alike, without all the nasties.</p>
</div>
```

With this CSS applied at present:

```
.twocol-text {
    -webkit-columns: 2;
       -moz-columns: 2;
            columns: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 84px;
       -moz-column-gap: 84px;
            column-gap: 84px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
       -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
            column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. There is no CSS way to determine which column an element is actually in since the columns are **styling** and not DOM elements.

Comment: Are you open to using javascript?

Comment: @sol I certainly am, although it's not a strong point of mine. You have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to check if the paragraph is on the left side of the container, and then add a class to right align the text.

The tradeoff is that it won't work for text that spills over between columns. Maybe the easiest way around that is to prevent it happening with CSS, but it can make the text imbalanced.

```js
const center = document.querySelector('.twocol-text').getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;

[...document.querySelectorAll('.twocol-text > p')].forEach(p => {
  const {
    left
  } = p.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (left < center) {
    p.classList.add('right-align');
  }
})
```

```css
.twocol-text {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 84px;
  -moz-column-gap: 84px;
  column-gap: 84px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
  column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
}

.right-align {
  text-align: right;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="centeralign largebotpad">Why no plastic?</h1>
<div class="twocol-text">
  <p>Over the past few decades, plastic has increasingly become an integral part of our daily lives. The issue with our reliance on plastic, though, is that this relationship comes at significant environmental cost.</p>
  <p>Water bottles, product packaging, textiles, grocery bags, and medical supplies, all contribute to the more than 400 million tons of plastic produced every single year worldwide. Of that, less than 10% is being recycled, and the vast majority is accumulating
    in landfills or sloughing off in the natural environment as litter.</p>
  <p>Plastic is also a threat to wildlife, creeping up in the food chain all the way to our plates. It is predicted that by 2050, there will be over 12 billion metric tons of plastic sitting in landfills. Yikes.</p>
  <p>In 2018 we decided to make our own line of clean containers and housewares that will be part of the solution. We opted for tried-and-true stainless steel as our main canvas to create elegant and minimalist, sturdy, and easy to clean products for children
    and adults alike, without all the nasties.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest I've been, Sol. Thank you for putting that bit of code together. I didn't realise it was possible to figure out which column something was in using JS. I might be able to do the rest with careful paragraph breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.twocol-text {
    -webkit-columns: 2;
       -moz-columns: 2;
            columns: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 84px;
       -moz-column-gap: 84px;
            column-gap: 84px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
       -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
            column-rule: 1px solid #496C4A;
}

.twocol-text-left p:first-of-type {
  margin: unset;
}

.twocol-text-left {
  text-align: right;
}

.twocol-text-right {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<?php if(get_field('intro_heading') ): ?>
  <h1 class="centeralign largebotpad"><?php the_field('intro_heading')?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="twocol-text">
  <?php the_field('intro_copy')?>
</div>

<h1 class="centeralign largebotpad">Why no plastic?</h1>
<div class="twocol-text">
    <div class="twocol-text-left">
    <p>Over the past few decades, plastic has increasingly become an integral part of our daily lives. The issue with our reliance on plastic, though, is that this relationship comes at significant environmental cost.</p>
    <p>Water bottles, product packaging, textiles, grocery bags, and medical supplies, all contribute to the more than 400 million tons of plastic produced every single year worldwide. Of that, less than 10% is being recycled, and the vast majority is accumulating in landfills or sloughing off in the natural environment as litter.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="twocol-text-right">
    <p>Plastic is also a threat to wildlife, creeping up in the food chain all the way to our plates. It is predicted that by 2050, there will be over 12 billion metric tons of plastic sitting in landfills. Yikes.</p>
    <p>In 2018 we decided to make our own line of clean containers and housewares that will be part of the solution. We opted for tried-and-true stainless steel as our main canvas to create elegant and minimalist, sturdy, and easy to clean products for children and adults alike, without all the nasties.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I say in the question the HTML is created dynamically from a single entry in the CMS database. It's therefore impossible to wrap in child elements that can be styled separately.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this. Since we always consider 2n element will have align left.

```css
.twocol-text {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.twocol-text p {
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.twocol-text p:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="centeralign largebotpad">Why no plastic?</h1>
<div class="twocol-text">
  <p>Over the past few decades, plastic has increasingly become an integral part of our daily lives. The issue with our reliance on plastic, though, is that this relationship comes at significant environmental cost.</p>
  <p>Water bottles, product packaging, textiles, grocery bags, and medical supplies, all contribute to the more than 400 million tons of plastic produced every single year worldwide. Of that, less than 10% is being recycled, and the vast majority is accumulating
    in landfills or sloughing off in the natural environment as litter.</p>
  <p>Plastic is also a threat to wildlife, creeping up in the food chain all the way to our plates. It is predicted that by 2050, there will be over 12 billion metric tons of plastic sitting in landfills. Yikes.</p>
  <p>In 2018 we decided to make our own line of clean containers and housewares that will be part of the solution. We opted for tried-and-true stainless steel as our main canvas to create elegant and minimalist, sturdy, and easy to clean products for children
    and adults alike, without all the nasties.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is a clever workaround. It creates irregular paragraph breaks though, which interrupt the flow of reading. It also re-orders the content of the text, meaning the read order is now: top left > top right > bottom left > bottom right. i don't think that will be clear enough for acceptable UX. Thanks though.